# Org-Mode Level Line Spacing

Tags: org-mode, todo

I am just starting to use Org-Mode as a getting things done application and having some trouble with the Line Spacing (not sure if that is the correct term) between entries.  For instance see below:

```
* TestPrimaryLevel1

** TODO Testing Spacing Level2 

*** Data associated with Testing Spacing Level3

*** More data associated with Testing Spacing Level3
```

There is an extra carriage return between each of the entries that I do not want to be there.  How can I default it to not adding that extra carriage return?

Comment: How (what **function**) did you use to create the headlines that inserted the extra carriage returns that you wish to remove?  Are you instead referring to a particular *folded view* perhaps -- if so, what folded view are using that you wish to change how it is displayed?  If you type `M-x show-all`, are the number of carriage returns between headlines to your liking?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can customize `org-blank-before-new-entry`.  See `C-h v org-blank-before-new-entry`.

Comment: This knocked it out.  Specifically using C-h v org-blank-before-new-entry and customizing it from there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the blank lines when collapsed with the following option:

```
(setq org-cycle-separator-lines 0)
```